# Does anyone have any experience with using the USB for io

Tags: android

I am doing this for a hobby type device where I am using the Android as a cheap why to get GPS and other hardware services (since I already have the phone).  I have used an unofficial kernel called AdbWinUsb that disconnects the USB from its usual use and makes it into an io port.  Has anyone else out there done this before successfully?  I have code to write out to the serial port:
      import java.io.DataInputStream;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.Messenger;

```
  DataInputStream os;      
  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
  os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /dev/ttyMSM0\n");
  ....
  String data = "echo \"Hello World\" > /dev/ttyMSM0";
  os.writeBytes(data + "\n"); 
  os.flush();
```

and this works great.

Then in another thread, I need to set up the read, but I can't write to the port to set it up as I did in the output....

```
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    os = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
    char xx = os.readChar();
```

The readChar doesn't work because it is not set up.  Is this correct?   So what do I do?

Comment: Instead of asking multiple, related piecemeal questions, please explain what overall end-to-end functionality you are trying to accomplish so others can provide some guidance about the plausibility of the path you are on.

Comment: You still do not have any attempt in your code to send data to or receive data from an I/O device, only an attempt to change its permissions.

Comment: You **STILL** have not posted any code which attempts to read or write an I/O port. You seem to be under the mistaken impression that "os" is an I/O stream to your port; it isn't, it goes to a shell process created by su.

Comment: You have finally updated it to reflect that os only accepts commands.  But for the input side, you would need a command to read the port.  This is unlikely to work well; either write your own command line tool to proxy data to and from the port (basically a primitive terminal program) or just do the port access from java now that you have given everyone permission  with the chmod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reference to any serial or USB port in the code you have posted.

Pushing "Test" into the stdin of whatever process 'su' gives you isn't going to accomplish much of anything.  You'll have better luck using su to chmod the device file of whatever device driver you have loaded to talk to whatever you plugged into the USB port (you do have a device driver loaded for that device, right?) and then talk to it from java, or to run a command line executable which proxies it's stdin/stdout to the device file for you.

What exactly have you plugged into the usb port?

If you can tolerate a higher external hardware cost, either the new, official ADK from google for recent android releases or the 3rd party IOIO (which should at least with modifications work on just about anything) may manage to abstract away more of the difficulty and connect you to more sources of support, though frankly having the accessory as the USB host is an unfortunate backwardness to have to resort to.

Comment: It is an arduano card.  That is a cheap card with two usb ports and a microprocessor.

Comment: Actually this is what was pushed into the standard out:

Comment: os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /dev/ttyMSM0\n");

Comment: /dev/ttyMSM0 is probably the super-low-voltage serial port on an EXTUSB connector, which you could easily damage by overvoltage.  If you have a USB-serial converter or the device-side serial port of an arduino, chances are your driver would give you ttyUSB0 or something like that (possibly something different for an arduino UNO?).  But in either case you have to have the appropriate driver built into the kernel or loaded.

Comment: Were you able to send bytes out the port to an external device successfully?  If not, it's likely early to worry about input from it.

Comment: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
      os = new   DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
      os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /dev/ttyMSM0\n");
      os.flush();  .... os.writeBytes(data + "\n");
      os.flush();

Comment: Edit your question, don't leave it saying something other than what you did and correct it only in the comments.

Comment: The above actually works when I load my kernel with the modified drivers.  The output data just flows into the arduino without problem.

Comment: No, the code you have posted does not work, as you have no write to an output device.  We cannot help you until you are fully accurate about what you are doing.

Comment: I was just mixed up.  I have to learn the proper etiquette here. You'll get me properly trained yet.

Comment: And it's likely these mixups why it is not working.  Try posting all of the code you expect to accomplish the task, and put comments in it about what each part is supposed to do.  This is likely to show that you are missing a step, or that some piece of code won't do what you think it's going to.

Comment: That is done.  Sorry for trying your patience.  I already can see that the main problem is that the input port is not set up correctly.  Or at all.

Comment: I think I see: chmod 777 /dev/ttyMSM0\n is there to setup the output port.  Ah-ha!  and the su is to set it to super user so I can setup the port.  Hmmm, so how do I do the same for the input port?  I can't write the bytes like I do with the input port.

Comment: You are setting up the port, but you are not making any attempt to either read or write it.  Unless the mysterious and undefined "data" that you push to the shell process is actually data embedded in a command, ie "echo \"hello world\"" - see why I'm on your case about not posting **ALL** of your code?  What you have posted is incapable of doing what you claim it does.

Comment: Sorry, my example should have been "echo \"hello world\" > /dev/ttyMSM0"

Comment: Yes that is correct and it is exactly as the sample code I received for the output data.

Comment: Ah, the echo sends the characters to standard out which are then redirected to the /dev/ttyMSM0 device which I suppose is the USB port was set up by that driver I loaded.  This is starting to make some sense.

Comment: Yes.  But after the chmod you should be able to do the access directly from java.  Though ttyMSM0 should not be a USB port unless the person who modified your kernel was very sloppy - that should be the _very_ low voltage serial port for example on the HTC EXTUSB connector, which is not part of "USB" at all.

Comment: You are undoubtedly correct about the it being the serial port on the HTC EXTUSB connector.  I have connected directly below the track ball on my Nexis One.

Comment: Oh, I just found the section on "Using Hardware Devices": http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html, let me read that.  Maybe if you have other links that would be helpful, I could read those also.

Comment: Could you give me a suggestion on setting up the input?

Answer (score 0):

I've just ordered a cheap bluetooth to rs232/ttl converter, then I'll use a PIC with UART to interface with the rs232. It seemed simpler, it means I don't need to know much about Bluetooth (or USB)